# How to change the value of .get().reduce( from parseInt to parseFloat

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing a mini system that will automatically compute the sum of the float numbers (1,124.35, 20,345.45, etc.) that will not round the number to integers when it computes the sum.

The result should be of type `float` and the total could in thousands.

Ex. **TOTAL: 24,345.25**

```js
jQuery($ => {

  const $expenses_debit = $(".expenses_debit"); //PS: Use a more specific selector than this one
  const $res_debit = $("#result_debit");

  $expenses_debit.on("input", () => {
    const total = $expenses_debit.get().reduce((acc, el) => (acc += parseInt(el.value, 10) || 0), 0);
    $res_debit.text(total);
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Due to BIR</td><td> <input type="number" class="expenses_debit"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Advances for Operating Expenses</td><td> <input type="number" class="expenses_debit"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Advances to Special Disbursing Officers</td><td> <input type="number" class="expenses_debit"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>TOTAL</td><td><output id="result_debit"></output></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `parseInt` use `parseFloat` in `reduce`.

```js
jQuery($ => {

  const $expenses_debit = $(".expenses_debit"); //PS: Use a more specific selector than this one
  const $res_debit = $("#result_debit");

  $expenses_debit.on("input", () => {
    const total = $expenses_debit.get().reduce((acc, el) => (acc += parseFloat(el.value, 10) || 0), 0);
    $res_debit.text(total);
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Due to BIR</td><td> <input type="number" class="expenses_debit"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Advances for Operating Expenses</td><td> <input type="number" class="expenses_debit"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Advances to Special Disbursing Officers</td><td> <input type="number" class="expenses_debit"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>TOTAL</td><td><output id="result_debit"></output></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Oh okay, i found my problem thats why parseFloat not working. i already tried this but somehow there are some error. Thank you